# Script tag inside ajax loaded html doesn't work when chrome dev tool is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, google-chrome-devtools

I am loading some HTML from server with ajax call using JQuery, when chrome dev tool is open, script inside loaded HTML works fine otherwise it doesn't execute. I have disabled cache in my ajax request as well. Here is my ajax request. It is also working fine in other browsers.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getContent.do",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    data: {owner: owner, code: code},
    success: function (result) {
       $("#loadScreen").html(result);                    
       $.unblockUI();                       
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
       console.log(xhr);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in browser console ?

Comment: no errors in console, it loads page but doesn't run JS inside script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax correct response only when Chrome devtool is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660078/ajax-correct-response-only-when-chrome-devtool-is-open)